# How do I use AngularJS to bind to a span that uses Livestamp?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use Angular data-binding to dynamically change the date used for Livestamp.

For instance, I would like to make the following dynamic:

```
<span data-livestamp="1413704094"></span>
```

by using Angular databinding, something like:

```
<span data-livestamp="{{item.Date.toISOString}}"></span>
```

How do I do it? The above code doesn't work.

EDIT:

Here's how it's used:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default messageItems" ng-repeat="item in vm.itemsTop | orderBy:'Id':true" ng-animate="'animate'">
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="media">
        <a class="pull-left" href="/People/{{item.User.Username}}">
            <img class="media-object" 
                 src="http://mysite/{{item.User.Username}})/avatar" 
                 alt="{{item.User.Username}}" />
        </a>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">
               <span ng-bind="item.User.Username"></span>
            </h4>
            <h6>
                posted <span data-livestamp="{{item.Posted.toISOString}}"></span> (<span ng-bind="item.Posted.toUTCString()"></span>)
            </h6>
            <p class="emojstext"> 
                 <span ng-bind="item.Text"></span>
            </p>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show the whole scope of the span, how do you define the ng-model ng-app etc

Comment: This span element is within a set of Bootstrap Panel divs, and it's being repeated by ng-repeat according to an array of items returned by a Breeze call.

Comment: upload a code sample to your question please

Comment: done. This is part of an ASP.Net MVC project and is used within a Partial View.

Comment: data-livestamp="{{item.Posted.toISOString}}" ==> data-livestamp="{{item.Posted.toISOString()}}"